# Can we generate detailed billing reports weekly and monthly using boto3 in aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, billing

Using Reports I am getting detailed billing information that automatically stores in S3 which are hourly and daily basis.

Is there any way that I can get billing information which is weekly and monthly basis?

Comment: HI, I found how to get the monthly reports.But how to get weekly reports?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look that what you want is possible. On [billing management -> preferences](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/preference) I can enable reports saved on s3, but the help text says:

> Turn on this feature to receive ongoing reports of your AWS charges *once or more daily*. AWS delivers these reports to the Amazon S3 bucket that you specify where indicated below.

So you can only get daily or sub-daily reports on S3